# IF statement and rand() function not working properly. (C++)

Tags: c++

Everytime i run this code, the IF statement does not strictly follow the condition given. it also displays "noway" sometimes when i generate a 1 or 2 and sometimes does not display it when i generate a 6 for example. I have no idea what's going on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0)) ;

    for(int x = 1; x <2; x++)
    {
        cout << (rand()%6) << endl ;
    }

    if((rand()%6) >= 3)
    {
        cout << " nowaay " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: the result of `time(0)` may be different for the successive times you call it (i.e.: you may be using different seeds)

Comment: `int x = 1; x <2` is **one** iteration. Why write a loop with such an hardcoded range at all?

Comment: Regarding this: " it also displays 'noway' sometimes when i generate a 1 or 2". The if statement is simply written to do that. It writes "nowaay" only when (rand()%6 <= 3). So in case of 1 or 2 it will write "nowaay" as they are <=3 and will not write in case of 6 as 6 > 3. Could you please clarify or make corrections on that part?

Comment: what do you expect from calling `rand()` twice?

Comment: Ah yes, I figured out I made a typo. But what I really meant was that IF statements do not output when the condition is true at times. Anyways, I got the mistake. Thank you people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value output by your first `rand()` call:

```
cout << (rand()%6) << endl ;
```

is not the same as the value tested in your second call:

```
if((rand()%6) <= 3) {
```

You cannot infer the later from the former. To get a grasp of it, replace your `if` test with:

```
const int alea = rand() % 6;
std::cout << "alea = " << alea << "\n";
if (alea <= 3) {
    std::cout << "way\n";
}
```

Comment: _outputed_? I'm not a native english speaker.